# Android : Unable to delete ListView item from menu

Tags: android, listview

I am new here so please bear with my naivety. I am working on a music player that will display a menu on clicking 'dots' buttton(given in code below) in listview item. Inside the menu there will be a button to delete. The listview is getting populated by a custom adapter. Here is the code of adapter...

```
   private class hashmapAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
HashMap<Integer, NowPlayingActivity.Details> NewDetails = new HashMap<>();

private hashmapAdapter(HashMap<Integer, NowPlayingActivity.Details> hashMap) {
    if(NewDetails.size()==0) {
        NewDetails.putAll(hashMap);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NewDetails.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return NewDetails.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View result;

    if(convertView == null) {
        result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item,parent,false);
    } else {
        result = convertView;
    }

    ((TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.Name)).setText(NewDetails.get(position).getName());
    ((TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.artist)).setText(NewDetails.get(position).getArtist());
    ((TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.duration)).setText(NewDetails.get(position).getDuration()+" || ");

    dots = (Button)result.findViewById(R.id.dots);
    dots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.Name);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popup_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_layout,null);
            RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) popup_view.findViewById(R.id.popup);

            final float width= (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.width_entry_in_dp));
            final float height= getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height_entry_in_dp);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow  = new PopupWindow(popup_view,Math.round(width),Math.round(height),true);

            popupWindow.showAtLocation(item, Gravity.END, 0, 0);
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(dots);

            play_next_btn = (Button)popup_view.findViewById(R.id.play_next);
            add_to_playlist = (Button)popup_view.findViewById(R.id.add_to_playlist);
            share = (Button)popup_view.findViewById(R.id.share);
            delete = (Button)popup_view.findViewById(R.id.delete);

            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for(int i=0;i<NewDetails.size();i++) {
                        if(NewDetails.get(i).getName().equals(name.getText().toString())) {
                            for(int j=0;j<hashMap.size();j++) {
                                if(hashMap.get(j).getName().equals(name.getText().toString())) {
                                    if (true) {
                                        NewDetails.remove(i);
                                        hashMap.remove(j);

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    populate1(NewDetails);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });

    return result;}
```

Now the problem is that after deleting element when i call populate1(NewDetails), it gives a null pointer exception on NewDetails.get(position).getName(). So on repopulating listview i am getting NPE error. Following is the populate1() function code...

```
 public void populate1(HashMap<Integer,NowPlayingActivity.Details> hashMap) {

    adapter = new hashmapAdapter(hashMap);
    library.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    library.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            String SongName = name.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NowPlayingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SongName",SongName);
            setResult(555,intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

I have already tried notifydatasetchanged() and listview.invalidateviews(), both didnt work. File is getting deleted but the adapter is not refreshing the list to remove element. Here is the xml layout of single_item for listview....`

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/element_shape_list"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/v11"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/art_work"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Name"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/art_work"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/art_work"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/art_work"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/art_work"
                android:layout_below="@id/Name">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/duration"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
                    android:ellipsize="end"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/artist"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/duration"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/duration"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dots"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="@string/vertical_ellipsis"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How are you letting the view know that a item was previously deleted?

Comment: i am removing item from the hashmap and repopulating the listview with the edited hashmap

Comment: All I can recommend is `adapter.clear();` just before `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` I also had a problem where item didn't want to be removed and this helped.

Comment: does not work...